# Open source login solution

Tags: linux, authentication, open-source

Authentication is such a general problem, which most websites have to implement. There are a few commercial solutions, but all lack sufficient functionality to customize the registration process. Therefore, I am looking for an open-source alternative. I am using PHP and with PostgreSQL as database, but as far as I understand one could utilize authentication solutions using other technologies and integrate them into our site in various ways. Therefore, I am looking for such solutions in any technology apart from those requiring Microsoft infrastructure...

I would prefer Open Source solution, which have already implemented the following features:

- Has password recovery procedure
- Username is the email address of the user
- Has "Remember me" functionailty (meaning that the user is logged in
  automatically without seeing the login page)
- email address verification

Google has gotten me nowhere on this and neither a search on this site...

Comment: In most frameworks this functionality exist and work properly. So if you start work with framework you can customise this functionality.

Comment: @b1- Would PHP be such a framework?

Comment: No, I mean frameworks like http://symfony.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one of these is of use for you: [opauth](http://opauth.org/) to interface with authentication providers or [uLogin](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/) for adding secure login and authentication capabilities. You would be able to develop the specifics on your own (remember me ...) but make a great use of proven basics.